# pass form data as url to d3.json method

Tags: html, forms, d3.js

I have an HTML form which has one input. This input I'd like to be a URL from which D3.json method would take it's data for building an illustration.

I'm wondering how can I pass this input? 
I suppose form's action can help, but I do not know how to pass variables using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just read the `value` property of the input and pass that to `d3.json`...

```
var myUrl = d3.select('#myTextBox').property('value');
d3.json(myUrl, function(error, json) {
  // do awesome stuff...
});
```

**EDITS**

```js
d3.select('#myButton').on('click', function(){
  var myUrl = d3.select('#myInput').property('value');
  d3.json(myUrl, function(error, json) {
      if (error) throw(error);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
<button id="myButton">My Awesome Action!</button>
```

Comment: ok, but how do I make it an action to be performed on submit?

Comment: @kaboom, what's you end goal here?  A `submit` is for submitting form data back to the server and to be honest, in this JavaScript heavy world, I don't seem them being used much anymore.  If you just have a textbox and then want a button to perform some action, just do that, forget the form.  See edits above...

Comment: end goal is to draw a graph out of whatever json is returned from URL in the input field.